# Django - Chart.js doesn't return nothing

Tags: javascript, django, chart.js

I'm new on js and i'm trying to build something simple. I've no error in the console but chart doesn't display on my Django website.
If someone can help me, please, would be great.

```
{% extends 'account/main.html' %}

<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
var defaultData = []
var labels = [];
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.default
        setChart()
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})

function setChart(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("myChart2");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx2, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: defaultData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'polarArea',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: defaultData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
}
// var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");



{% endblock %}
</script>

{% block content %}


<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>


    <form method="GET" action="" name="myform" value="home" id="subform">
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
```

Comment: Try narrowing down the scope of the issue. Can you render the chart with static data? If so then the issue is with the ajax call. If not, then you know the issue is with the configuration or rendering of the chart.

Comment: is there any error in the javascript console?

Comment: Nope, no errors at all, neither in console